# How to access a JavaFX ImageView from another class

Tags: java, javafx, scope

I have recently implemented a simple JavaFX GUI. I have a class extending TableView, which references an ImageView(constructor parameter). Once a row is selected. The program get's the row's object string. Which then is assigned to the ImageView.

This is the original code, which was working in the main method.

[image]

```
        tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
        if (newSelection != null) {
            String imageID = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().IMAGE_ID;

            try{
           Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("/resources/fellowshipcards/"+imageID).toURI().toString());
                cardImageView.setImage(image);
            }catch(Exception ex){}

        }
    });
```

But when I try to add it as a parameter - an error occurs. The ImageView cannot be accessed. Simple the imageView.setImage(image) doesn't execute.

```
  public TableViewCenter(ImageView cardImageView){
```

....

```
              try{
                Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("/resources/fellowshipcards/"+imageID).toURI().toString());
                System.out.println(imageID);
                cardImageView.setImage(image);
            }catch(Exception ex){}
```

Once the row is selected, the system exectes everything, without the .setImage(image) function.

It might be a scope problem or is it JavaFX accessing different components problem.

Comment: How are you exposing cardImageView from within the tableview?  Is the ImageView a part of your new table view??  if so - you likely need something like tableView.getCardImageView().set()...

Comment: In main method -> ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
 -> MyTableView myTableView = new myTableView(imageView);


MyTableView instance is insterted into HBox with ImageView. I tried to separate the code, from the main. And make MyTableView object (Practicing OOP)

Comment: I don't understand the structure.  Can you put all your code there?

Comment: ImageView objects are just like every other Java object. You can pass references to them around to other classes and methods just as you would with anything else.  Show us the code where the public TableViewCenter(ImageView cardImageView) method is defined, and where it is called.

Comment: [MyTableView.class](https://pastebin.com/WVR6haLU) Check lines: 19, 55 ,64
[Main.class](https://pastebin.com/VtJ7Y5we) Check lines: 30, 175, 187

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem! The implementation of the listener should be declared in the class where the imageView is located